# React on initialization errors for ec2 autoscale instances

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, autoscaling

I have an webserver running on EC2 behind ELB which is scaled using AWS AutoScale. When a new instance starts it fetches the most recent application code from a git repository.

What's the best way to react on any errors during initialization?

- git server might not be up/reachable
- disk might be corrupt, git pull exists with an error (yes this has happened to me)

Comment: Put your production version zipped up on S3 and pull it from there.

Comment: what if that doesn't work for some reason?

Comment: Hmm maybe create a cron job to check if you app is deployed and re download it if it isn't.

Comment: And have downtime meanwhile? And that won't help against a corrupt disk.

Comment: I don't know that there is a perfect solution when automating anything. Errors can happen. Have you looked at Elastic beanstalk it will at least launch another instance if it has an error.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I did:

- on start up create a file `instance_starting`
- once initialization finished successfully delete this file
- the ELB health check accesses a special url that returns Error 500 if the `instance_starting` file exists
- a cloudwatch alarm that reports me unhealthy instances